# How to fetch data from database using angular 6 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I did code to fetch data from database using angular 6 and typescript code for fetching data. In backend, I am using java spring boot. But I am not able to find data from the database.

I used spring interpolation code to fetch data from database

```
this.profileService.updatepostedjob(this.postedjob.id,{jobrole: this.postedjob.jobrole,descriptions:this.postedjob.descriptions,}).subscribe(data => {console.log(data); 

this.postedjob = data as Postedjob;},error => console.log(error));}
```

I want to fetch data from database but data is not coming.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the issue.

Comment: Is your backend work correctly? Does it give the data you require?

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth Actually I did code for fetching data from database this means Data is coming from my database on frontend for display

Comment: @DilanTharaka Yes Sir backend is working fine

Comment: what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth No Error came in compile time and runtime but its not working

Comment: please make this app in satckblitz so that we can see the code and fetching the issue.

Comment: @PavanNagadiya Ok I will do on satckblitz  and then checked the error

Comment: @ANUPAMKR ok...

Comment: What is the data that you're getting and how are you trying to display

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth My data is simple like a employee details and I am trying display in table format .

Answer (score 0):

- Hope you must be having url in controller to handle the request, repository mapping to fetch the data from database, using HTTPClient in angular.
- First of all try to hit the backend url from postman. If you are
  getting error, that simply means there is issue with you backend code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked in postman Data is sending to database,                                                        Also HTTPClient is used in module.

Answer (score 0):

1. test your url,make sure it is working - get data that you want
2. import http in the nearest module,like this:

```
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    ....
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [Component1,Component2],
    imports: [CommonModule,HttpClientModule ] })
    export class MyModule{}
```

3. this is your component code:

```
    arrData:any[];
    constructor(http:HttpClient){}
    ...
    initComponent(){
        this.http.get(yourUrl).subscribe(
            (val)=>this.arrData = val,
            error=>console.log('errors while get data from remote server')
        );
    }
```

4. now,you get your data - arrData

Comment: at browser console,data is not printed ?

Comment: Yes Data is not printed on browser console